# Kendo UI MVVM with Kendo UI Drag and Drop

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I am attempting to use the Kendo UI MVVM framework with the Kendo UI drag and drop mechanic; But I am having a very difficult time finding out how to get the data dropped out of the `draggable` object.

My code is something like this ...

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable {
    Cart : [],
    Items : [
    {
      Id : "item/10",
      Name: "CD ROM"
    },
    {
      Id : "item/11",
      Name: "DVD ROM"
    }
};
```

So then I have a rough template binding...

```
<script id="products-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li class="draggable">
        <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
    </li>
</script>
```

Then this gets called up in a list...

```
<div id="shopping-items-available">
   <ul data-template="products-template" data-bind="source: Items">
   </ul>
</div>
```

Then there is a standard "drop target" (taken from the kendo docs)

```
<div id="droptarget">Start dragging.</div>
```

with the following CSS

```
#droptarget {
    border: 1px solid #959595;
    height: 198px;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 36px;
    border-radius: 37px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 198px;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
    margin: 0 0 30px 220px;
    cursor: default;
    background: #dddddd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd 0%, #c1c1c1 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#dddddd), color-stop(100%,#c1c1c1));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd 0%,#c1c1c1 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd 0%,#c1c1c1 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd 0%,#c1c1c1 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #dddddd 0%,#c1c1c1 100%);
}
```

Now in the javascript, I turn the `shopping-items-available` div into a `draggable`.

```
    $("body").kendoDraggable({
        hint: function (target) {
            return $(target).clone().addClass("draggable");
        },
        filter: ".draggable"
    });
```

and lastly, I initialize the drop target.

```
    $("#droptarget").kendoDropTarget({
        drop: droptargetOnDrop
    });
```

but in my code, I cannot seem to get the actual data about the item that was dropped.

```
    function droptargetOnDrop(e) {
        console.log(e);
        $("#droptarget").text("You did great!");
        $(".draggable").removeClass("hollow");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data of the item being dropped is received by `droptargetOnDrop` as `e.draggable.currentTarget`.

If you want to move the item to the target area, you should do something like:

```
$("#droptarget").append(e.draggable.currentTarget);
```

*NOTE* Doing this, you will be moving the item. If you want to append a copy, you should append a clone of the node:

```
 $("#droptarget").append($(e.draggable.currentTarget).clone());
```

**EDIT**: For getting the data item without using a kendoDataSource I propose to change the template to:

```
<script id="products-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li class="draggable" data-id="${Id}">
        <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
    </li>
</script>
```

This saves the `Id` (or any information that allows you to find the element latter) in the DOM being dragged. Then in the handler we retrieve the `Id` and search the item corresponding to that `Id`.

```
function droptargetOnDrop(e) {
    var dom = e.draggable.currentTarget;
    var id = $(dom).data("id");
    var items = viewModel.Items;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].Id == id) {
            alert("Found : " + JSON.stringify(items[i]));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** If you decide to use `kendoListView` you should define your template as:

```
<script id="products-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li class="draggable">
        <div>${Name}</div>
    </li>
</script>
```

The HTML container for the list would be:

Then initialize the ListView as:

```
var list = $("#shopping-items-available > ul").kendoListView({
    template  : $("#products-template").html(),
    dataSource: viewModel.Items
}).data("kendoListView");
```

and finally the `droptargetOnDrop` function:

```
function droptargetOnDrop(e) {
    var dom = e.draggable.currentTarget;
    var item = list.dataSource.getByUid(dom.data("uid"));
    alert("Found : " + JSON.stringify(item));
}
```

Comment: Will this actually move the item _and_ underlying data, or just the DOM nodes? I am mostly concerned with the actual data, because it needs to get passed up through the view model so that server side stuff can take place.

Comment: Hrnm, I tried this and it doesn't work. I still cannot access the actual data of the underlying object that is part of the view model.

Comment: The "data" being things like the Name and Id of the Item, not the DOM elements.

Comment: Is it possible define `shopping-items-available` as a Kendo UI List View?

Comment: I do not think so. I had really wanted to avoid using that. Is that the only possible way?

Comment: No but it is (for me) the cleanest (because then you can have a DataSource and retrieve the dataSource and the data item). Are you interested in the "tricky one" (not using listview)?

Comment: I am not completely against using a ListView if I have to, but I am having to drop some of this into already running environments, so using as few style changes as possible is my preferred approach.

Comment: Aha, so I have to just hook into it externally and do a forced loop through the view model. That is pretty dirty... I'm dissapointed that they don't have some kind of binding already made for the drag and drop tool.

Regardless, this is exactly what I needed to do! Thank you very much!

Out of curiosity, what if I _were_ using a ListView? Is there a listed sample that shows how to do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35041/discussion-between-onabai-and-ciel)